# Why does Java's `.dateLastModified` get truncated in some Windows 7 files?

Tags: java, windows, datetime

I'm writing a backup program because Windows refuses to let me use its backup program for some reason. (I get an error code that I can report if need be.)

I only want to copy a source node file that is NEWER than a destination node file with the same name.

I found that, even though the last modified date in Windows `Properties` for two files showed to be identical, the source was almost invariably being copied--even though it's NOT newer.

[image]

[image]

Here are declarations:

```
File from_file = new File(from_name);
File to_file   = new File(to_name)
```

Here's what I finally found for two files in different folders with the same name.

The last 3 digits returned by `.lastModified()` may be NONzero for one file and ZERO for the other even though the dates shown in the `Properties` windows for the files appear identical.

My question is WHY would that be the case???

After much frustration and debugging, I have a workaround:

```
 destinationIsOlder = ((long)(from_file.lastModified()/1000)*1000 
                       > 
                       (long)(  to_file.lastModified()/1000)*1000);
```

But WHY do I have to do that? I.e., what is Windows doing? Should it do this? Is it a bug?

And what other similar evil awaits me?

I.e., should I divide by a larger integer than 1000?

(It's not the end of the world to copy a file that's technically and incorrectly reported to be a few milliseconds newer, but it's a lot of wear and tear on the drive if it happens for every single file in the source folder and subfolders!)

(I may have just stumbled onto why `xcopy` didn't do what I wanted, either.)

*EDIT* The times returned by the two calls shown above were

`1419714384951` from `from_file.lastModified()` and

`1419714384000` from   `to_file.lastModified()`. Therefore, although identical, including displayed date and time, `from_file` is newer and thus, by rule, copied, but inappropriately.

Comment: So what's the actual values you are getting from lastModifled() ? Note that the lastModified() time is in miliseconds, you're only seeing seconds resolution in the windows dialog. A bit of experimentation can probably reveal how windows rounds or truncates the time as shown in the GUI - but that shouldn't matter if you're trying to determine which file is newer.

Comment: java.io.File is obsolete, and, having been around since Java 1.0, does a lot of things poorly.  Consider using [Files.getLastModifiedTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-) instead;  it returns FileTime objects which are mutually Comparable, and which (potentially) have greater granularity than a millisecond.

Comment: (1) -- @nos--Refer to my EDIT for the times returned. (2) -- @VGR--I didn't know `File` was obsolete; it's not deprecated; but I'll look into `Files`. Thanks to both.

Comment: @VGR--but how do I compare `Files.getLastModifiedTime(fro)` and `Files.getLastModifiedTime(to)` where `Path fro = Paths.get(from_path.toString())` and `Path to = Paths.get(from_path.toString())`?

Comment: Surely the point is that it is *not* truncated, except by the Properties dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lastModified returns a long with millisecond precision - therefore the last 3 digits represent the fraction of a second.

Since the file properties dialog only displays time up to the second, the two files will show the same value.

Why are some zero and some non-zero? Lots of reasons. If the file is copied from somewhere else with only second precision, it will be zero. If an application explicitly changes the file modification time, it might only do it with second resolution. And so on.

In the end, I don't think it should affect your backup scheme that much for you to worry about it.